# ValueError Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas

So Im trying to add a new column using panda with this

```
print(sorted(v, reverse=True))
df['VALUE'] = [np.array([v])]
df.to_excel('E:/.../result.xlxs')
```

and error with message: ***ValueError Length of values does not match length of index***

But when I check the number of elements from each with this code

```
jkl = len(alt)
lkj = len(v)
print(jkl == lkj)
```

the value is ***TRUE***

Comment: So? I don't see anywhere in those first three lines that indicates the length of `alt` matters at all.

Comment: Try `df['VALUE'] = np.array(v)`

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yes finally it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

May try to omit the extra square brackets around and inside the `[np.array([v])]` expression and write it like this: `np.array(v)`. With them it makes it a length 1 list, without them it should match the length you checked in the second code block.